# If $f$ is a continuous, either $f$ is constant or $\int_{0}^{1} f(t) \, dt < \max_{x\in[0,1]}f$.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, continuity, riemann-integration

Our situation:

We have a a function $f$ that is continuous on [0,1] and
$M=\max\{f(x) : x \in [0,1]\}$.

We WTS that either f is constant ($\forall x \in [0,1] \space f(x)=M$) or that $\int_{0}^{1} f(t) \, dt < M.$

Intuitively I know this is true but it becomes a bit harder to prove. This is what I have so far:

Firstly f can be the function $g(x)=M$ because g is continuous and non-neg on [0,1] and M is naturally the maximum of $g$ on $[0,1]$.

The harder part is if $\exists x \in [0,1]$ such that $f(x) < M$ (f is not constant):

Since f is continuous it is Riemann integrable which means if $U(f)$ is the upper integral of $f$ on $[0,1]$ ($U(f) = inf\{U(f,P) : P \in X\}$ where $X$ is a collection of all partitions of $[0,1]$ and $U(f,P)$ is a upper sum) then $U(f) = \int_{0}^{1} f(t) \, dt.$ (This is probably the part I am least confident about)

Let P be a partition of [0,1] then $U(f,P)= \sum_{i=0}^{k-1} M_i(a_{i+1} - a_{i})$ where $M_i$ is the supremum of $f$ on that interval. Then $U(f,P)<  M\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}(a_{i+1} - a_{i})=U'(f,P).$ Note that we have a strict less than because f is not constant.

Then we have $\int_{0}^{1} f(t) \, dt = U(f) \leq U(f,P) < U'(f,P)=M$ which means $\int_{0}^{1} f(t) \, dt < M$.

Does this proof look ok?

Comment: "if $\forall x \in [0,1] \space f(x) \neq M$ (f is not constant)" This is not true. $f·$ is nonconstant if there exists $x_0\in[0,1]$ such that $f(x_0)<M$.

Comment: Ah your right. Updated. Does my proof work with that change?

Comment: Where do you use EXACTLY that $f$ is continuous (and not only continuous implies integrable)? MOreover... Why "$M\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}(a_{i+1} - a_{i})=U'(f,P).$" is true?

Comment: I think the only place I use the fact that f is continuous is there. For the second part, I'm just defining $U'(f,P)$ to be that quantity (perhaps I should have just wrote $U'$) and it equals M since the partition has length 1. Also I want to use the idea of uppersums to prove this since that was what was suggested by my prof.

Comment: If so, your "proof" will work also for every integrable function such as $f(0)=1$ and $f(x)=0$ $x\in(0,1]$. That $U'$ is NOT an upper sum. So your proof fails.

Comment: Sorry I'm having a hard time understanding which part of the "proof" I wrote you are mentioning. Are you saying that $\int_{0}^{1} f(t) \, dt = U(f) \leq U(f,P) < M$ is not true because i messed up somewhere earlier in the proof?

Comment: The problem is that $M_i\le M$ and not, in general, $M_i<M$. To show the strict inequality you should use continuity and nonstantness. My otther counterexample do not works. But use $f(x)=1$ for $x\in[0,1]\setminus{1/2}$ and $f(1/2)=0$. This function is not constant but its integral equals its maximum. The problem is that given any partition, for THAT function, $M_i=M=1$ always.So, you only have that $U(f,P)\le M$ and taking infimum $U(f)\le M$ (wich is trivial).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f$ is not constant, then there exists an $x_0\in (a,b)$, such that
$$
f(x_0)<\max_{x\in [a,b]} f(x)=M
$$
If we set $2\varepsilon=M-f(x_0)$, then there exists a $\delta>0$, such that
$$
|x-x_0|<\delta \quad\Longrightarrow\quad |f(x)-f(x_0)|<
\varepsilon=\frac{1}{2}\big(M-f(x_0)\big)
\quad\Longrightarrow\quad
|f(x)-f(x_0)|<\frac{1}{2}M-\frac{1}{2}f(x_0)
\quad\Longrightarrow\quad
f(x)<\frac{1}{2}M+\frac{1}{2}f(x_0)
=M-\varepsilon
$$
Hence
$$
\int_a^b f=\int_a^{x_0-\delta} f+\int_{x_0-\delta}^{x_0+\delta} f+\int_{x_0+\delta}^b f \le (x_0-\delta-a)M+2\delta (M-\varepsilon)+(b-x_0-\delta)M \\=(b-a)M-2\delta\varepsilon<M.
$$

Comment: how did you drop the absolute values when going from $|f(x) - f(x_0)| < \epsilon$ to $f(x)-f(x_0) < \epsilon$?

Comment: @LTM I believe that the proof is now fixed.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Try to prove that if $0\le F(x)$ is continuous and strictly positive elsewhere in $[0,1]$, then $\int_0^1F(x)dx>0$. And apply it to $M-f(x)$.